# How do I fix up this SQL Query in my PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I got a MySQL Query I'm trying to run and I just can't work out how to fix it.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO ratings (epoch, ip, step, maxstep, threadid) VALUES
('."shell_exec(date             +%s.)".','.mysql_real_escape_string(inet_pton($_COOKIE[".id."])).','.$page.', '.$pagedecode[".numpages."].', '.$ourid.')'";
```

I know it's really bad :(
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Thanks
Jamie

Comment: `sql` isn't a valid PHP variable, it should be `$sql`. And why are you calling the shell command `date` -- PHP has built-in date functions that can do this.

Comment: I had a $sql it's just I was having problems with indenting it so I removed the $ but then got it working and forgot to add it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ratings (epoch, ip, step, maxstep, threadid) VALUES ('" . shell_exec(date +%s.) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string(inet_pton($_COOKIE[id])). "','" . $page . "','".$pagedecode[numpages]."', '".$ourid."')'";
```

but the query is vulnerabe with `SQL Injection`. Please read the article below to learn how to prevent for it

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Why is it open to SQL Injection? The only value that the person can alter or provide is the id in the cookie. Also still get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%' in your code

Comment: The argument to `shell_exec` needs to be quoted, and there shouldn't be a `.` in it.

Comment: @JamieH - As you correctly point out, the id in the cookie can be altered on the client side. That is the definition of SQL injection.